# Updating ItemsControl when new Item is added to the ItemsSource

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8

Okay this seems like a pretty easy thing to do, but I've been looking for a solution for over an hour and couldn't come up with anything. In my WP8 application, I have an `ItemsControl` which I bind data procedurally. The bound data is a static `ObservableCollection`. When I add new items to this collection via another page, I expect to see the new item on my `ItemsControl`. After adding a new item to the collection, the `ItemsControl` still looks empty, even though its `ItemsSource` seems to contain items.

Edit: The code I wrote looks like below

The ItemsControl is defined on the page as follows:

```
<ItemsControl Name="MyItemsControl" 
                              Grid.Row="4"
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding someData}" 
                                           Margin="24"
                                           Foreground=""/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Binding is handled as follows:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
     MyItemsControl.ItemsSource = SomeClass.myObservableCollection;
}
```

Class where the static collection resides:

```
class SomeClass 
{
    public static ObservableCollection<MyData> myObservableCollection { set; get;}
}
```

MyData:

```
class MyData
{
    public string someData { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code - ItemsControl, ObservablrCollection? Do you see Itmes if you add them via MainPage?

Comment: You have to update or refresh your Control in order to see your new item.

Comment: @Romasz I hadn't tried that, but it seems like it doesn't matter where I add the new item.

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov Yeah that's what I thought, but I couldn't find how to.

Comment: Do you have any code? I can show how I did it in my example...

Comment: @halileohalilei Then there is probably something wrong with your ItemsControl. CAn you show the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that your ObservableCollection is null, if you want to use property it can look like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private static ObservableCollection<MyData> myObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();

    public static ObservableCollection<MyData> MyObservableCollection
    {
         get { return SomeClass.myObservableCollection; }
         set { SomeClass.myObservableCollection = value; }
    }         
}
```

Then:

```
MyItemsControl.ItemsSource = SomeClass.MyObservableCollection;
SomeClass.MyObservableCollection.Add(new MyData() { someData = "Romasz" });
```

And of course it can be even easier (if you don't need property):

```
public static ObservableCollection<MyData> myObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
```

And you can move `MyItemsControl.ItemsSource = SomeClass.MyObservableCollection;` to the constructior of your Page - there is no need to do it every time you Navigate to the Page.
And remove `Foreground=""` from your XAML code.
**EDIT** - after comment
It's hard to say for me where can be a problem as I don't see your whole code, but please consider this example which works fine for me:
In XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="MyItemsControl" Grid.Row="3">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding someData}" Margin="24"/>
               </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In code behind:

```
class SomeClass
{
   public static ObservableCollection<MyData> myObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();
}

class MyData
{
   public string someData { set; get; }
}

public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   MyItemsControl.ItemsSource = SomeClass.myObservableCollection;
   SomeClass.myObservableCollection.Add(new MyData() { someData = "First" });
   SomeClass.myObservableCollection.Add(new MyData() { someData = "Second" });
}
```

Comment: I actually initialize `myObservableCollection` somewhere else, so I'm sure it's not null. The problem is, I can see that new items are added to `myObservableCollection`, but I can't see them being displayed on the screen inside `MyItemsControl`.

Comment: @halileohalilei And this Foreground="" is not there as I assume?

Comment: Lol yeah that was a mistake. I actually wondered if that was causing the problem, turns out it doesn't. My data is still not being updated.

Comment: Can you try to run the code I've posted after Edit? Also make your someClass and MyData public if you want to access tchem from other classes/pages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of updating data

```
private void UpdateData()
        {
            try
            {
                MainWindow.cmdSel = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Cities order by ID asc", MainWindow.conn);
                DataSet dtst = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(); 
                try
                {

                    adpt.SelectCommand = MainWindow.cmdSel;
                    adpt.Fill(dtst, "Cities");
                    lstCity.DataContext = dtst;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }


            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
```

After you add some items in your ListItem

```
    private void AddCity(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TxtCity.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            Add(TxtCity.Text);
            UpdateData();           ////Here I am updating my listitem
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Add city");
        }

    }
```

Comment: OP has binding to ObservableCollection which should in teory update `automatically` his Control, when he adds or removes Items from ItemsSource. And as he has said - he doesn't see items at all.

Comment: Can you show your code? You can try YourControl.Items.Refresh();

Comment: I don't see how this answer relates to what I've asked. My problem is that the items, which are added to the items source after the `ItemsControl` is initialized, are not displayed on the screen.